# Telnet Clients and Their Treatment of EOL

Tags: c, sockets, networking, blackberry, telnet

This is a rather convoluted question, and for that I apologize. I wrote a Linux C sockets application, a basic framework for a simplistic chat server. The server is running on my laptop. The client is Telnet at the moment until I write a designated client application (that'll be more secure, hopefully). There are better applications for sending generic network data from a client end, I know, but I got interested about *why* a certain thing happens on one Telnet client but not another.

The first Telnet client test was on another Linux laptop. It works as expected. The next, however, was a Blackberry app called BBSSH that allows Telnet and SSH connections. I went via the Telnet option, and it works too. Except, it doesn't exactly.

The server code does the usual `read` call to retrieve a block of data, which gets treated as a string, i.e. a message. The former client reads until I hit enter, and then it sends one string of characters. The BB app, however, sends every single character as if I've been pressing enter after each of them, which I haven't. Obviously this is something to do with buffering, what certain clients class as a EOL from the user input, etc. I just can't pinpoint it.

To illustrate, here is the server outputting messages it's received from the clients.

First, the message from the Linux client:

```
client name: this is a test
```

Now, for BBSSH:

```
client name: t
client name: h
client name: i
client name: s
client name:
client name: i
client name: s
client name:
client name: a
client name:
client name: t
client name: e
client name: s
client name: t
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telnet clients can operate in line-mode or character-mode. The BBSSH client seems to be operating in character-mode for some reason.

It's possible that your server could force the client into line-mode by sending the client an instruction to that effect during the negotiation that takes place at the start of a telnet connection.

The byte sequence your server would need to send to the client is 0x255 0x253 0x34, which translates as "Interpret As Command, Do, Linemode". If the client is willing/able to operate in line-mode, it should reply with 0x255 0x251 0x34 ("Interpret As Command, Will, Linemode").

If this is all new to you (i.e. your telnet server currently doesn't do any negotiation at all), google for terms like "telnet negotiation" or take a look at some of the relevant RFCS (RFC 854 is Telnet itself, RFC 1184 covers the Linemode option).

Comment: Ahh... I suspected it was to do with two clients running in different configurations or modes. The behavior seemed too consistent to be a server-side read-amount fluke. Given that the Telnet client is merely a test bed, and the client will eventually use TCP directly, I'll only embed that mode byte sequence temporarily. Thanks for the RFC numbers, I'll look them up :)

Comment: Even if the client sent the data in complete lines, wouldn't it still be susceptible to TCP fragmentation?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yes, you could still get TCP-level fragmentation, however that's not what's causing the problem described in the question. Additionally that kind of fragmentation needs to be solved at a protocol level above either of TCP or Telnet - in this question that's a job for the 'chat protocol' really.

Answer (score 2):

TCP is stream-orientated, and so there's no such thing as a "message". You might receive all the data together, or just a fragment of it at a time.

In your case, you might want to buffer anything received until you hit an EOL marker.

Comment: I meant 'messaging' as an abstract concept for my application, I know it's all stream and buffer based. I assumed read would block until it receives EOF, filling up the buffer until that point is met?

Comment: By default with a TCP socket, `read` just blocks until some data (any data) is available. That might be one byte, or it might be a whole line.

Comment: Ah, I see. That confuses me though. So how does read know how many bytes to read before stopping when data becomes available?

Comment: It may return as soon as _any_ data is available - you're just lucky if you get the whole line at once, and you're just as likely to get half of a line or two lines together. You will have to keep calling `read` and looking for EOL markers in the received data.

Comment: Do you think that the consistent behavior is because Linux's Telnet client automatically buffers lines before EOL, so the server receives it all in one go due to the client?

Comment: Yep, but even with that you can't guarantee the lines won't be fragmented after being sent by the client.