# Python server echos before hitting the enter key

Tags: python, telnet

I've faced an odd problem and I cannot figure out what the reason is! Actually, I've written a simple server in Python which echos whatever the client enters. To test it, I connected to server by telnet, but as soon as I enter a character, it will become echoed! I do not know how to stop it! Actually I want to complete a word and after hitting the enter key, my server echos it. 
Here is my simple server:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 5000 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        reply = 'OK...' + data
        if not data: 
            break     
        conn.sendall(reply)

conn.close()
s.close()
```

Comment: `conn.recv()` doesn't wait for a newline.

Comment: So what can I use instead? Something which waits for a newline

Comment: I have this problem too, and to have to solve it server side is a pain.  The problem is this: In the Mac, telnet opens in linemode.  You can also specify mode line, or mode character.  But on Windows Telnet, it opens in character mode and there is no mode command to change it!!!  In fact, I haven't found ANY way to get linemode in Windows (XP) telnet!

Answer (score 4):

According to the `telnet` man page, the client attempts to enter linemode, and will fallback to character mode if the remote server doesn't support it:

> Once a connection has been opened, telnet will attempt to enable the TELNET LINEMODE option.  If this fails, then telnet will revert to one of two input modes: either “character at a time” or “old line by line” depending on what the remote system supports.

You can change your server-side code to handshake with the client for enabling line-by-line, or you can force the client to use an "old" line-by-line mode, where it buffers the characters locally, and sends them all at once.

To do the former, you should be able to send the following sequence of bytes after the initial connection as [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724033/276949):

```
0x255 0x253 0x34
```

To do the latter, you can do (press ctrl right bracket first), which will enable this mode in the telnet client (assuming you are using the BSD telnet command - on Windows it may be different).

```
^]toggle localchars
```

Comment: He **could** change his server code to parse the data and wait until it gets a newline.

Comment: Yeah Martin, I've already checked this question before, but it could not solve my problem. As you mentioned, I guess I have to find a way to stop my terminal from sending keystrokes immediately, but I do not know how!

Comment: Changed my answer - it appears there is server-side support or client-side support for this.

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks for your help, but finally I solved the problem by changing my code, as Barmar said. Actually, I buffered all received data and after receiving "return" all of the will be echoed.